# switch from mobile menu to default menu with pure css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

currently I am trying to create a navigation bar that switches itself to a hamburger menu if the screen size is too small (responsive / mobile).

https://jsfiddle.net/g7tfnry1/31/

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#btn").click(() => {
    $("#items").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#navbar {
  background: red;
}

#items {
  display: flex;
}

#btn {
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 300px) {
  #items {
    display: none;
  }
  #btn {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">
  <button id="btn">X</button>
  <div id="items">
    <div>
      <a>
        Link 1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a>
        Link 2
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a>
        Link 3
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So if you lower the screen size to mobile the css works fine. If you show the items by clicking the button the css works fine too. But after that if you want to get back to a big screen size the menu disappears completely because the items are still hidden or the items don't get aligned in a flex box next to each other.

My question is, do I have to create a resize event `$(window).resize()` or am I missing something in my css?

Comment: ?You've set `#btn {display: none}` for screens > 300.

Comment: `toggle()` hides the elements, independent of any CSS. Which means you *must* `.show()` them to make them visible again. One way to solve this with pure CSS is to have two independent menus, one for mobiles and one for desktops, and show/hide them in their entirety based on the window's width. However I wouldn't worry too much about this specific issue anyway, because people don't usually resize their windows while browsing a website.

Comment: @ChrisG No, they _"don't usually resize their windows while browsing"_, but they might flip a phone between portrait/landscape, and then it becomes an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `.toggle` (show/hide) you override the CSS rules as it change the display type *inline*, which has a higher [*specificity*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than external rules, unless `!important` is used in the CSS.

Instead toggle a class `.toggleClass`, combined with an extra CSS rule `#items.show`

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vu5wg1ze/)

Stack snippet

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#btn").click(() => {
    $("#items").toggleClass('show');
  });
});
```

```css
#navbar {
  background: red;
}

#items {
  display: flex;
}

#btn {
  display: none;
}

/*  temp. changed to 500 so it works better in the snippet/Chrome when resize  */
@media(max-width: 500px) { 
  #items {
    display: none;
  }
  #btn {
    display: block;
  }
}

#items.show {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="navbar">
  <button id="btn">X</button>
  <div id="items">
    <div>
      <a>
        Link 1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a>
        Link 2
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a>
        Link 3
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```